# How to apply the transitive law when there is a $\le$

Tags: inequality

The transitive law states that:

For real numbers $a$, $b$ and $c$:

$a<b \text{ and } b<c \Rightarrow a<c$

I am not sure how to apply it in the following cases ($x \in \mathbb{R}$):

1. $a \le x \text{ and } x \le b$
2. $a \le x \text{ and } x \lt b$
3. $a \lt x \text{ and } x \le b$

After doing some exercises, it seems that the answer is as follows:

1. $a \le b$
2. $a \lt b$
3. $a \lt b$

I don't know how to apply the transitive law to arrive at the answer. My solution was $a \le b$ for all 3 cases as I thought that would account for the cases where $a<b$ and/or $a=b$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Example 2, suppose that $a \leq x$ and $x < b$. Then there are exactly two cases to consider:

- **Case 1:** Suppose that $a < x$. Then since $x < b$, it follows by your transitive law that $a < b$.
- **Case 2:** Suppose that $a = x$. Then since $x < b$, it follows by substitution that $a < b$.

Thus, in either case, it follows that $a < b$, as desired.

---

A similar argument can be applied for Example 3. To see why Example 1 is different, note that it involves four cases, one of which is the case where $a = x$ and $x = b$. In this case, we would get $a = b$, while in the other three cases we would get $a < b$. So we would summarize these four cases by saying that $a \leq b$.

Answer (score 1):

Example 1: If $x=b$ then $a\leq x$ implies $a\leq b$. Similarly if $a=x$. So the only real case is $a<x$ and $x<b$ and then $a<b$. So you can deduce that $a\leq b$.

Comment: I still don't see it. Could you please try to explain with Truth Tables instead and also demonstrate example 2?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by using truth tables in this case...

Comment: I thought the truth of any statement can be evaluated using truth tables like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table.